# jQuery: How can i enable the disabled anchor tag

Tags: jquery

Hi i am trying to enable the disabled anchor tag based on getting REST response. I tried following:

```
  function enableDisableButton(data) {
  if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", false);
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", true);
      }
  }
```

my HTML:

```
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="setDefault">
            <br />
            <a id="setDefaultGraph" class="btn btn-small btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="#setDefaultGraphModal" name="setDefaultGraph" disabled>Set as default!</a>
            <a id="unsetDefaultGraph"  class="btn btn-small btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="#unsetDefaultGraphModal" name="unsetDefaultGraph" disabled>Remove as default!</a>
        </div>
```

I have disabled the anchor tags on page load & should behave sa required on user input. But nothing is working..

Any help will always appreciated...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to do what you are trying to do with JavaScript alone instead of JQuery, to see if the problem was from JQuery use ? I solved a lot of my JQuery problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
   function enableDisableButton(data) {
     if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
         $('#setDefaultGraph').attr('disabled', true);
         $('#unsetDefaultGraph').attr('disabled', false);
         } else if(data.defaultStatus == false){
         $('#setDefaultGraph').attr('disabled', false);
         $('#unsetDefaultGraph').attr('disabled', true);
      }else{
         return false;
            }
    }
```

use attr instead of prop

Comment: you need to make disabled=""  in your html while loading the page then only it will work

Comment: this is the right one i havent made it equal to.. only added diasbled. Thanks.. Your attr code is working correct

Answer (score 2):

Add a data property to the link depending on the condition. And on click event on the anchor tag check for that property. Try with -

```
  if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').data("disabled", true);
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').data("disabled", false);
  } else {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').data("disabled", false);
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').data("disabled", true);
      }
  }
```

Check the property on click event -

```
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
     if ($(this).data('disabled')) {
         e.preventDefault();
     }
  })
```

**Update**

If you want to stop the links from displaying `modal` -

```
$('#setDefaultGraph').data("toggle", '').css('color', '#ccc');
```

add the css to look like it is disabled.

Comment: thanks for the response but your method is not working!

Comment: i am calling the modal on click so no need of check just on response i need to disable or enable the anchor tags based on response

Comment: Then on set the `data-toggle` property blank. Then it will not open the modal then. and add some css class to show it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it, This will surely work :

```
function enableDisableButton(data) {
  if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", true);
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
      $('#setDefaultGraph').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('#unsetDefaultGraph').prop("disabled", true);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an HTML objects attributes it's better to use `attr` just like the way you used `prop`. [More information](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
function enableDisableButton(data) {
if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
    $('#setDefaultGraph').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#unsetDefaultGraph').attr("disabled", false);
} else {
    $('#setDefaultGraph').attr("disabled", false);
    $('#unsetDefaultGraph').attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to disable anchor if u click it won't go anywhere, Kindly correct me if am wrong.

```
 if (data.defaultStatus == true) {
      $("#setDefaultGraph").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
     }
```